# how to stop a paypal ticket transction from going through?

Tags: paypal

There's a website with a bunch of handwritten html paypal code: ie, sample beneath:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

                    <!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@address.org">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Luncheon">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Luncheon Ticket"> 
                    <label>Select the number of tickets you would like to purchase:</label> 

                    <select name="amount">
                        <optgroup label="Luncheon's Ticket">
                             <option value="45">1 Ticket - $45</option>
                             <option value="90">2 Tickets - $90</option>
                             <option value="135">3 Tickets - $135</option>
                             <option value="180">4 Tickets - $180</option>
                             <option value="225">5 Tickets - $225</option>
                             <option value="270">6 Tickets - $270</option>
                             <option value="315">7 Tickets - $315</option>
                             <option value="360">8 Tickets - $360</option>
                             <option value="405">9 Tickets - $405</option>
                             <option value="450">10 Tickets - $450</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Names and Vegetarian Meals"><label>List guests' names and indicate if vegetarian meal is needed</label>
                    <input type="text" name="os1" placeholder="e.g., Jane Doe (vegetarian), John Doe">
                    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                     <input type="submit" value="Purchase Ticket(s)" name="submit" title="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" class="paypal_btn expanded large button">
                     </form>
```

We are pulling down the code as we don't want to sell anymore tickets. But apparently, some people keep the paypal pages open for days ... not kidding here. So, when they're ready to purchase the tickets, the transaction goes through.

Is there a way short of cancelling (not really an option here) to prevent the tickets from going through?

For clarification, the page will no longer have paypal tickets available. But as stated, people keep the page open for days. Hence this whole quandary.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the transaction from going through with the code above?

EDIT

Kind of realized that I stated this question badly because I didn't think completely what I wrote down here. I asked if there's anything I can do to prevent the transaction from going through with the code above. But the code is going to be pulled down today ... so ... is there any other means to prevent the transactions from those people who leave those pages open for dayyyyyyssssss?!?!?!?

Comment: Is anything else coded to allow transactions through donations? Otherwise not sure what you could do here as this is submitting a donation.

Comment: @DavidNguyen, um, not sure what you mean. But no, nothing else is coded besides the code above.

Comment: @DavidNguyen, added an edit above.

Comment: What am saying is currently the code shown is submitting a donation - technically the only way to block it is to stop all donations (if possible in Paypal). Do you have other things that are purchased the same way?

Comment: @DavidNguyen, if you mean the same paypal account yes. if you meant this specific page, yes, there were three sets of tickets which since then have been pulled down. I thought of meta-refresh tag, but the other person didn't like that solution since it's kinda annoying. so, the only thing i've implemented since then is the no-cache meta-tag thing so, hopefully people who left these pages open for days hit refresh, and the tickets are gone! this is not for people who left the ticket pages open. sigh.